# How to correctly specify maxPriorityFeePerGas?

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-price, eip-1559

I am trying to send a transaction quickly by adding a priority fee that is half the base fee with the following logic:

```typescript
const { baseFeePerGas } = await client.getBlock();

const priorityFee = baseFeePerGas / 2n;

const hash = await wallet.writeContract({
  account,
  address,
  abi,
  functionName,
  args,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: priorityFee,
  maxFeePerGas: baseFeePerGas + priorityFee,
});
```

When I go to use this it throws an error which states I was trying to provide over 13 ETH worth of wei to the transaction but 9 gwei for the priority fee and 28 gwei for the max fee seems what I would expect it to be.

```
Insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x035342Fb880F46A9F58343774F131Bf6f6757007 have 77717615752227236 want 13418145387500000000 (supplied gas 500000000)

Contract Call:
  maxPriorityFeePerGas:  8.945430258 gwei
  maxFeePerGas:          26.836290775 gwei
  data:                  0x3eb76b9c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013f
  to:                    0xBE5E6De0d0Ac82b087bAaA1d53F145a52EfE1642
  from:                  0x035342Fb880F46A9F58343774F131Bf6f6757007
```

Shouldn't the max gas used be no more than 26836290775 wei (26.836 gwei) in this scenario? Where does the 13418145387500000000 wei come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here is with the [gas limit](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#what-is-gas-limit) and not the gas price.

As it mentions in the error: `gas (limit)` * `price` + `value` = `funds used in tx`

You are providing a huge gas limit (500,000,000), so currently the formula works out to be:

`500,000,000` * `26.8 gwei` + `value` = `13418145387500000000 wei`

Which is more than the balance of the wallet (`77717615752227236 wei`)

You will want to estimate the actual gas limit before sending the transaction. In Ethers.js this is available via the provider's `estimateGas()` [function](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#Provider-estimateGas).